# Grails: Checking environment from inside BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: grails, configuration, environment

In Grails it is a convetion that `Environment.current.name` will tell us the name of the environment specified during the `run-app` invocation:

```
grails run-app -Dgrails.env=testing
```

However `Environment.current.name` isn't available to check from inside `BuildConfig.groovy` like so:

```
if(Environment.current.name == 'testing') {
    // do something else
}
```

Since `Environment.current.name` isn't available in `BuildConfig.groovy`, is there any other way to tell what environment was specified?

Comment: Have you looked at using System.getProperty('grails.env') since you are using an environment variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grails.util.Environment` is the preferred way to check the current environment, even in `BuildConfig.groovy`.

The problem appears to be with the condition in your if statement. The test Environment is called "test", not "testing", and so should look like
`if(Environment.current.name == 'test')`

You can avoid the magic string by using the enum constant
`if(Environment.current == Environment.TEST)`

Or avoid the if statement altogether using the `executeForEnvironment` which takes a closure, eg:

        `Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.TEST) {
            // do some stuff just for the TEST environment
        }`